# Magnetic field of rotating capacitor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, classical-mechanics, particle-physics

Does the rotating charged capacitor (both plates) produce magnetic field? and what about rotating both plates in opposite directions?

Comment: classic construction of a capacitor is 2 foils separated by a dielectric compuond, which is high viscisity and acts liks glue, so not mobile.  Old radios used rotating plates to generate a harmonic frequency, matching the carrier waves.  maybe some ideas there, but not exactly what you're thinking, i'm sure

Comment: yes,"where you rotate the plates in opposite directions, does create a measurable current! The average current would be twice the charge on one of the plates, divided by the period of rotation. Rotating the plates faster would produce more current." so when two plates of capacitor rotate in the same direction their magnetic fields cancel each other out?
for instance capacitor mounted on shaft and surrounded by coil or near hall sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real world is messy and annoying, so *maybe*.

But it *shouldn't*.

Magnetic fields are created by currents, and the direction of a current depends on both the direction in which charge carriers move *and* the sign of the charge that is moving. When you spin a whole capacitor, in any orientation, you move both positive and negative charge carriers in the same direction- thus, the currents that *would* be generated by each on individually cancel out.

If, however, you manage to separate the plates and rotate them in opposite directions, then their currents would add, and you should get a net magnetic field.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up! but one more thing... also if one plate is rotating will other plate self rotate because plates are bound by line of force? if so then in what direction second plate will self rotate?

Comment: @szufla Depends on the specific geometry involved, but most likely not. If, for example, you have two parallel plates and rotate one around an axis perpendicular to the plates, the electric field will not transfer any torque.